# Run interactive Bash with popen and a dedicated TTY Python that capture SIGINT

Tags: python

I saw this example that launches bash thru subprocess where asynchronous read/write is achieved. However I wonder if there is a way to preserve this behavior and capture a keyboard interrupt.

[Run interactive Bash with popen and a dedicated TTY Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542960/run-interactive-bash-with-popen-and-a-dedicated-tty-python/43012138#43012138)

This is my version of the code. The issue is python code is not INTERRUPTED.

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os

import signal
import atexit
import select
import termios
import tty
import pty

def execute(command):

    old_tty = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
    tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())

    master_fd, slave_fd = pty.openpty()

    process = subprocess.Popen(command,
                     preexec_fn=os.setsid,
                     stdin=slave_fd,
                     stdout=slave_fd,
                     stderr=slave_fd,
                     universal_newlines=True)

    global child_pid
    child_pid = process.pid

    while process.poll() is None:
      r, w, e = select.select([sys.stdin, master_fd], [], [])
      if sys.stdin in r:
          d = os.read(sys.stdin.fileno(), 10240)
          os.write(master_fd, d)
      elif master_fd in r:
          o = os.read(master_fd, 10240)
          if o:
              os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), o)

    output = process.communicate()[0]
    exitCode = process.returncode
    if (exitCode == 0):
        return output
    else:
        raise ProcessException(command, exitCode, output)


def exit_protocol():
    global child_pid

    if child_pid is None:
        pass
    else:
        print "Shutting Down bash", child_pid

atexit.register(exit_protocol)

try:
    execute('bash')

except KeyboardInterrupt as exc:
    print "Clean up all bash's child jobs"
```