# Run interactive Bash in dumb terminal using Python subprocess.Popen and pty

Tags: python, linux, bash, tty, pty

This question is similar to [Run interactive Bash with popen and a dedicated TTY Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542960/run-interactive-bash-with-popen-and-a-dedicated-tty-python), except that I want to run Bash in a "dumb" terminal (`TERM=dumb`), and without putting the tty into raw mode.

The code below is my attempt. The code is similar to the solution given in the linked question, with the major difference that it does not put the tty into raw mode, and sets `TERM=dumb`.

```py
import os
import pty
import select
import subprocess
import sys

master_fd, slave_fd = pty.openpty()

p = subprocess.Popen(['bash'],
                     stdin=slave_fd,
                     stdout=slave_fd,
                     stderr=slave_fd,
                     # Run in a new process group to enable bash's job control.
                     preexec_fn=os.setsid,
                     # Run bash in "dumb" terminal.
                     env=dict(os.environ, TERM='dumb'))

while p.poll() is None:
    r, w, e = select.select([sys.stdin, master_fd], [], [])
    if sys.stdin in r:
        user_input = os.read(sys.stdin.fileno(), 10240)
        os.write(master_fd, user_input)
    elif master_fd in r:
        output = os.read(master_fd, 10240)
        os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), output)
```

There are two problems with the code above:

- The code will re-echo whatever the user inputs. For example, if the user inputs `printf ''`, the code above will print `printf ''` on the next line before printing the next bash prompt.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> do not behave as one would expect in `bash`.

How should I fix these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly the side effects of not putting the tty in *raw* mode. Usually a program (like [expect](/questions/tagged/expect)) which handles pty would put the outer tty in *raw* mode.

- Your Python script's tty (or pty) echos what you input and the new pty echos for the 2nd time. You can disable ECHO on the new pty. For example:

  ```
  $ python3 using-pty.py
  bash-5.1$ echo hello
  echo hello
  hello
  bash-5.1$ stty -echo
  stty -echo
  bash-5.1$ echo hello    # <-- no double echo any more
  hello
  bash-5.1$ exit
  exit
  ```
- Your Python script's tty is not in *raw* mode so when you press <kbd>ctrl-d</kbd> Python would not get the literal <kbd>ctrl-d</kbd> (`'\004'`). Instead, Python would reach EOF and `read()` returns an empty string. So to make the spawned shell exit you can

  ```
  user_input = os.read(sys.stdin.fileno(), 10240)
  if not user_input:
       # explicitly send ctrl-d to the spawned process
       os.write(master_fd, b'\04')
  else:
       os.write(master_fd, user_input)
  ```
- Similarly, the Python's tty is not in *raw* mode so when you press <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd>, it'll not get the literal <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd> (`'\003'`). Instead it's killed. As a workaround you can catch `SIGINT`.

  ```
  def handle_sigint(signum, stack):
      global master_fd
      # send ctrl-c
      os.write(master_fd, b'\03')
  signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_sigint)
  ```

Comment: I found that I can use termios to disable ECHO like this: `import termios`; `slave_attr = termios.tcgetattr(slave_fd)`; `slave_attr[3] = slave_attr[3] & ~termios.ECHO`; `termios.tcsetattr(slave_fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, slave_attr)`.

Comment: With your SIGINT handler, why does Ctrl-c cause `^C^C` to be displayed instead of only `^C` (as would be expected from `TERM=dumb bash`)?

Comment: each pty outputs a ^C

Comment: Okay, I found that I must do `stty -echoctl` to prevent the echo of a second `^C`.

Comment: Suppose I replace `['bash']` with `['ssh', 'user@example.com']`. Why does Ctrl-c cause the script to exit instead of displaying the next prompt in the SSH session?

Comment: with or without the SIGINT handler?

Comment: Oh, never mind. There is no problem. I was looking at the wrong code.